# How to make variable available everywhere in Java without parameters

Tags: java, jvm, new-operator

yes hi, i would like to make the variable in the following, (schoolsubjects) available everywhere (such as in methods like, getItems() ) however without using parameters. I do not know the formal definition of what I am trying to do, that is why i cant really google this.

```
import java.util.*;
public class TestApp{
    private static String[] schoolsubjects;
    public void TestApp(){

    }
    public void addItem(String item_name){
        schoolsubjects.add(item_name);
    }
    public void getItems(){
        return schoolsubjects;

    }


}
```

ok thank you

in addItem()

I get, error: cannot find symbol

Comment: You're actually asking the community to teach you Java, right ?

Comment: actually im asking "How to make variable available everywhere in Java without parameters"

Comment: Normally people move away from global variables and pass parameters 'cos that's usually better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have it now schoolsubjects is available to all methods within that class. i.e. getItems() already has access to schoolsubjects. Though it should be noted you cannot return an array from a method with a return type of **void**, you will want to change `public void getItems()` to `public String[] getItems()`

Comment: String[] objects don't have an "add" method. You might want to use an ArrayList or a Vector.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is answered by Oracle's [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html).  [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) is a link to the section that is most relevant to your specific question.  However I recommend that you read the whole lot ... or at least the trails that cover the basics.